# Error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'namn' of Lärare.Lärare

Tags: c#, object

When trying to create a new instance of

```
Lärare L = new Lärare();
```

I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'namn' of 'Lärare.Lärare(string, int, long, string, int, bool, int)'   LogicLayer  C:\Users\famil\Desktop\Sysvet\OOSU1\lab 2\Högskolan\LogicLayer\Program.cs   20  Active

I have tried to change it to `Lärare L = new Lärare(namn, personalID, personnummer, email, telNr, adminRights, lärarLagsID);`

as the default constructor is

```
    public Lärare(string namn, int personalID, long personnummer, string email, int telNr, bool adminRights, int lärarLagsID)
    {
        Namn = namn;
        PersonalID = personalID;
        Personnummer = personnummer;
        Email = email;
        TelNr = telNr;
        AdminRights = adminRights;
        LärarLagsID = lärarLagsID;
    }
```

But then I only get

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0165  Use of unassigned local variable 'namn' LogicLayer  C:\Users\famil\Desktop\Sysvet\OOSU1\lab 2\Högskolan\LogicLayer\Program.cs   20  Active

for every variable except for adminRights

What I'm trying to achieve is to create an instance so I can add the information to a list.

The class Lärare implements an interface called IPersonal which has the following variables and methods in it

```
 string Namn { get; set; }

    int PersonalID { get; set; }

    long Personnummer { get; set; }

    string Email { get; set; }

    int TelNr { get; set; }

    bool AdminRights { get; set; }

    int LärarLagsID { get; set; }

    string läggTillLärare(string Namn, int PersonalID, long Personnummer, string Email, int TelNr, bool AdminRights, int LärarlagsID);

    void taBortLärare(string Namn, int PersonalID, long Personnummer, string Email, int TelNr, bool AdminRights, int LärarLagsID);
```

ps. Its a school project where we have to implement an interface on all classes we use.

Comment: The error message is saying you have used the variable `namn` before you have assigned any value to it. Check to see if the variable has been assigned a value before you use it to create the object `L`. If you are still having an issue, please post ALL of the relevant code

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://www.ideone.com/Eue77P).

Comment: Off topic, but you should really try to keep your code in English, and you should also try to follow c# naming conventions

Comment: If the _default_ constructor requires all of the parameters, what do you expect `Lärare L = new Lärare();` to do? If you use `Lärare L = new Lärare(namn, personalID, personnummer, email, telNr, adminRights, lärarLagsID);` to supply the values, then where did _those_ values come from?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, I have managed to solve it by changing the class I was referring to Personal and creating a new class called Larare where I only implement an interface and a default constructor with basically the same variables as the old.